# restrict AndroidFileBrowser to go up further than startdir

Tags: android, restrict, file-browser

I want to use [AndroidFileBrowser](https://github.com/vaal12/AndroidFileBrowser) to create a simple Browser in my App.
Is there a way to prevent users to go up further than the provided startDirectory I give the activity via Intent? How would I have to change the code in FileBrowserActivity.java?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't implemented... You have to change the

```
loadDirectoryUp()
```

method. Just check if the current directy is the same as your "start" directory. If true, don't let the user go up a folder.